# Kenya's army is not to be messed with

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

[Grid in plaintext](https://pastebin.com/bCerhnc1)

**Across**
1. Standing in front of a dark, large entrance of estate that can be rented (8)
5. County worker, perhaps seen near border (6)
10. Wife of Abraham Lincoln (5)
11. Staunched, broken or safe and sound? (9)
12. Varna riots concerning former kingdom (7)
13. Article repeatedly describing laser boiling water (4,3)
14. Ability to shoot accurately indicates male person is trendy (12)
19. Massive monorail cast adrift (12)
22. Large amphibians from wetlands around full-flowing river (9)
25. Mitten swapped hands in woodland (5)
26. Bad, bad sign for corporation (7)
27. Rise again, responding to a king in admiration (7)
28. Doctor Valentine's maybe brought back some of suitors' spirits (6)
29. Doctors introducing me to ten STDs – horrible (8)

**Down**
1. Metal cans banged to drive away Charlie Chaplin, perhaps (4,4)
2. An anteater is the first of animals on a road leading to entrance of vacant fauna transport ship (8)
3. A soup eater finally has one text showing words of wisdom (9)
4. Thelma's partner, extremely irritating, wanting to be a pest (5)
6. African detained by Kenya's army (5)
7. Have another discussion about cannabis (6)
8. Inhabitant of Iran, once equally far from both extremities (6)
9. Booth, maybe of two seats, at home (8)
15. According to hearsay, next in line delivered on the wing? (8)
16. Alien I authorize to receive 2,000 ships, essentially (9)
17. Scientists puzzled – loch in the grips of coronavirus disease (8)
18. Moles and voles, finishing with serious disease, taking pill (8)
20. Flying abroad in a plane, say (6)
21. On vacation, girl welcomes boy extremely proudly and happily (6)
23. Cultivated, expressing right to be noted (5)
24. Deliver legal document of free verse (5)

Comment: 25A seems ambiguous(?)

Comment: @oAlt Ugh, you're right -- I should have phrased that differently. rot13(V trarenyyl nibvq "va" nf n pbaarpgbe orgjrra jbeqcynl naq qrsvavgvba, juvpu vf jul V gubhtug gurer'f bayl bar jnl gb cnefr gung pyhr. Ohg bs pbhefr gurer'f ab jnl sbe fbyiref gb xabj gung, naq znal choyvpngvbaf qb nyybj "va" nf n pbaarpgbe.)

Comment: ohh, i see (and i kinda agree)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solved grid:

> [image]

Clue explanations:

> [image]

Comment: (I still haven't figured out where the S in 3D comes from, or what's going on with LEPERS in 18D.)

Comment: "text" can be SMS :0

Comment: @oAlt Ah, of course!